# Trigger a shell script in Azure

Tags: bash, azure, http, triggers, kubernetes

I'm using a Kubernetes cluster in Azure running an ingress controller. The ingress controller routes to different services via a given context root.

To add another service and connect it to my ingress I build a simple shell script looking like this:

```
kubectl apply -f  $1'-svc.yaml'
some script magic here to add a new route in the hello-world-ingress.json
kubectl apply -f 'hello-world-ingress.json'
```

I tested the script on my local machine and everything works as expected. Now I want to trigger the script with an HTTP rest call on Azure.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that? So far I know:

1. I need the Azure cli with Kubernetes to run the kubectl command
2. I need something to build the HTTP trigger. I tried using AzureFunctions, but I wasn't able to install the Azure cli in Azure Functions on the Azure Portal and I wasn't able to install Azure cli + Azure Functions in a Docker Container.

Does anyone have an idea how to trigger my shell script via HTTP in Azure in an environment where the Azure cli exists?

Comment: why do you think you need azure cli? where should this run? anywhere that can connect to k8s or on k8s? i mean, whats your target?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to set up an Azure instance with `kubectl` and the Azure cli configured to talk to your cluster and on that same server setup something like [shell2http](https://github.com/msoap/shell2http). For example:

```
shell2http -export-all-vars /mybash "yourbash.sh"
shell2http -form /apply "kubectl apply -f  $v'-svc.yaml'"
shell2http -export-all-vars /domore "domore.sh"
```

Where `$v` above is the name of your deployment.